# C won't recognize negative numbers as input

Tags: c, if-statement, operators

This program is meant to take three whole numbers as input and return the minimum. This was my first attempt:

```
int first, second, third;
printf("Please enter three numbers:\n");
scanf("%d %d %d", &first, &second, &third);
int min;
if (first<second && first<third) {
    min = first;
} else if (second<first && second<third) {
    min = second;
} else {
    min = third;
printf("The minimum value is: %d\n", min);
}
```

It worked for everything except negative numbers. If an input was negative, it would not return anything. Then I changed the code to this:

```
if (first<second ) {
    if (first<third)
        min = first;
    else
        min = third;
} else if (second<first) {
    if (second<third)
        min = second;
    else
        min = third;
    min = second;
}
printf("The minimum value is: %d\n", min);
```

This version worked perfectly, but I don't understand why the first one wouldn't work for negatives. What's the difference?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what was happening? What do you mean by "it would not return anything?" Was it crashing, not responding to input, or something else?

Comment: In v1 your `printf` is only in the `min=3` branch. Either you have incorrectly cut and paste your code, or else your code only prints in that one case (and just to note, v2 doesn't print anything at all ever...)

Comment: That last `min = second;`  is completely wrong.  It does not work perfectly.

Comment: @John3136 You're right! That did it, thank you! Although now I don't understand why it worked fine with positives if it had an error like that... (I left out the printf on v2 because I didn't think it was relevant to the problem. In the future is it recommended to post the whole piece?)

Comment: @user9484 If you enter 1 2 3 in v1 does it work? Doesn't look like it should. As for what to post: as little as possible. In this case since the questions is really about what got printed out, then including the print is pretty relevant.

Comment: Also beware that your first example's intended logic is wrong.  If you have inputs `1 1 2`, it would give you `2`.  You should use the `<=` operator, not `<`.

Comment: @paddy Good point, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You had the printf in the else{printf} it should be outside:

```
    int first, second, third;
printf("Please enter three numbers:\n");
scanf("%d %d %d", &first, &second, &third);
int min;
if (first<second && first<third) {
    min = first;
} else if (second<first && second<third) {
    min = second;
} else {
    min = third;
}
printf("The minimum value is: %d\n", min);
}
```